# How to download a file from AWS S3 and access it in iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have looked all of this forum and the web and could find nothing to help me with this. I have a text file stored on my S3 server and I need to download it to my iOS app and read the file as a string. I can access the server and have an output stream open to save the file. When I try to access the file right after, it doesn't exist. It would be awesome if someone has down exactly this and could just walk me through it, but anything will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSURLSessionDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)downloadMethod
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourFileURLString"]];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];

    defaultConfigObject.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;

    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
         [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

         if (error == nil && data != nil)
         {
              NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
              NSLog(@"String is: %@",theString);
         }             
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! One last thing, how do I use the URL for downloading without making the file public?

Comment: Youll need to ask another question, and accept my answer